# Excel: How to color cells based on condition A = C and the sum of values in B is less than D?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formatting, formula, conditional-formatting

Column A, starting from A1, contains the following values:

sasa
masa
sasa
masa
sasa
sasa
sasa
vasa
vasa

Column B, starting from B1, contains the following values:

2
3
4
5
6
4
1
1
2

Column C, starting from C1, contains the following values:

sasa
vasa
masa

Column D, starting from D1, contains the following values:

10
11
1

I want to highlight in green all the values in column B that, when summed from the current row up to the top, are less than or equal to the sum of values in column D. The condition is that the value in column A must be equal to the corresponding value in column C.

In this case, the following cells in column B would be highlighted in green:

B1 and B3 (values 2 and 4) because their sum, looking from B1 to B3, is less than the value in C1 (10) for the name "sasa."
B8 and B9 (values 1 and 2) because their sum, looking from B8 to B9, is less than the value in D2 (11) for the name "vasa."

"I tried using conditional formatting in Excel with a formula, but I couldn't get it to work as expected. I expected the formula to highlight specific cells in column B when they met the criteria of being less than or equal to the sum of corresponding values in column D and having the same value in column A as in column C. However, the conditional formatting didn't highlight the cells correctly. I also attempted to use VBA code, but that didn't produce the desired results either. So, I'm looking for an alternative solution or guidance on how to accomplish this task."

Comment: B1 and B3 Do not match on A3 and C3

Comment: Try this? =AND(EXACT(A1,C1),SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))>SUM(D:D))

Answer (score 0):

Idk how to create conditional formating with that logic, but i found formula and hope helping u

if u need something, le me know, thanks :)

For this formula just need 1 additional colummn to create, and next step u just create conditional formating with Text

```
=IFERROR(IFS(AND(A1=$C$1,SUMIF($A$1:$A1,A1,$B$1:$B1)<$D$1),TRUE,AND(A1=$C$2,SUMIF($A$1:$A1,A1,$B$1:$B1)<$D$2),TRUE,AND(A1=$C$3,SUMIF($A$1:$A1,A1,$B$1:$B1)<$D$3),TRUE),FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: after more trying I did not success :(